# Unfixable memory leak

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, trie

I apologize for the long code snippet ahead, but I spent a good while looking on here and I feel like nothing I've seen so far can help me solve this. I've asked questions on course forums, had TAs help, and have gotten suggestions from friends and nothing has been able to lock down the root of my problem here.

In this program, I am using a tree to create a spell-checker. There are many things that need to be fixed in my code, but the memory leak is the only one I really need help figuring out.

The issue is that I am fairly sure I am allocating the correct amount of space for my nodes, and I think Valgrind confirms this, because I only have 2 not-freed blocks (out of 365,371 allocs).

Anyway, I will post the entirety of the code (in case anyone needs the full context), but the relevant parts I presume are the load function and the clear function, where I allocate and free the memory, respectively.

```
/**
c* Implements a dictionary's functionality.
*/
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// number of characters we are using (a-z and ')
#define LETTERS 27

// max guaranteed number of nonnegative char values that exist
#define CHARVALUES 128

// create node structure for trie
typedef struct node
{
    struct node *children[LETTERS];
    bool is_word;
}
node;

// create root node for trie
node *root;

// stores the size of our dictionary
unsigned int dict_size = 0;

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // keeps track of where we are; starts with root for each new word
    node *current_node = root;

    while (*word != '\0')
    {

        // indices: 'a' -> 0, ..., 'z' -> 25, '\' -> 26
        int index = (tolower(*word) - 'a') % CHARVALUES;
        if (index >= LETTERS - 1)
        {
            // by assumption, the char must be '\'' if not '\n' or a letter
            index = LETTERS - 1;
        }

        // if the node we need to go to is NULL, the word is not here
        if (current_node->children[index] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // go to the next logical node, and look at the next letter of the word
        current_node = current_node->children[index];
        word++;
    }
    return current_node->is_word;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // allocate memory for the root node
    root = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // store first letter (by assumption, it must be a lowercase letter)
    char letter = fgetc(inptr);

    // stores indices corresponding to letters
    int index = 0;

    /**
     * we can assume that there is at least one word; we will execute the loop
     * and assign letter a new value at the end. at the end of each loop, due
     * to the inside loop, letter will be a newline; we know the EOF in the
     * dictionary follows a newline, so the loop will terminate appropriately
     */
    do
    {
        // keeps track of where we are; starts with root for each new word
        node *current_node = root; 

        // this loop will only execute if our character is a letter or '\''
        while (letter != '\n')
        {
            // indices: 'a' -> 0, ..., 'z' -> 25, '\' -> 26
            index = (letter - 'a') % CHARVALUES;
            if (index >= LETTERS - 1)
            {
                // by assumption, the char must be '\'' if not '\n' or a letter
                index = LETTERS - 1;
            }

            // allocate memory for a node if we have not done so already
            if (current_node->children[index] == NULL)
            {
                current_node->children[index] = malloc(sizeof(node));

                // if we cannot allocate the memory, unload and return false
                if (current_node->children[index] == NULL)
                {
                    unload();
                    return false;
                }

            }

            // go to the appropriate node for the next letter in our word
            current_node = current_node->children[index];

            // get the next letter
            letter = fgetc(inptr);
        }

        // after each linefeed, our current node represents a dictionary word
        current_node->is_word = true;
        dict_size++;

        // get the next letter
        letter = fgetc(inptr);
    }
    while (letter != EOF);

    fclose(inptr);

    // if we haven't returned false yet, then loading the trie must have worked
    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return dict_size;
}

void clear(node *head)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++)
    {
        if (head->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            clear(head->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(head);
}

    /**
     * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
     */
    bool unload(void)
    {
        clear(root);
        return true;
    }
```

The relevant valgrind output is the following:

```
==18981== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18981==     in use at exit: 448 bytes in 2 blocks
==18981==   total heap usage: 365,371 allocs, 365,369 frees, 81,843,792 bytes allocated
==18981== 
==18981== 448 (224 direct, 224 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==18981==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18981==    by 0x4011B0: load (dictionary.c:111)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:40)
==18981== 
==18981== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18981==    definitely lost: 224 bytes in 1 blocks
==18981==    indirectly lost: 224 bytes in 1 blocks
==18981==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18981==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18981==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18981== 1 errors in context 3 of 11:
==18981== 
==18981== 
==18981== Invalid read of size 8
==18981==    at 0x40120C: load (dictionary.c:123)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981==  Address 0xb3fde70 is 16 bytes before a block of size 224 alloc'd
==18981==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18981==    by 0x4011CB: load (dictionary.c:111)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981== 
==18981== 
==18981== 1 errors in context 4 of 11:
==18981== Invalid read of size 8
==18981==    at 0x4011E0: load (dictionary.c:114)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981==  Address 0xb3fde70 is 16 bytes before a block of size 224 alloc'd
==18981==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18981==    by 0x4011CB: load (dictionary.c:111)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981== 
==18981== 
==18981== 1 errors in context 5 of 11:
==18981== Invalid write of size 8
==18981==    at 0x4011D4: load (dictionary.c:111)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981==  Address 0xb3fde70 is 16 bytes before a block of size 224 alloc'd
==18981==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18981==    by 0x4011CB: load (dictionary.c:111)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981== 
==18981== 
==18981== 1 errors in context 6 of 11:
==18981== Invalid read of size 8
==18981==    at 0x4011B2: load (dictionary.c:109)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
==18981==  Address 0xb3fde70 is 16 bytes before a block of size 224 alloc'd
==18981==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18981==    by 0x4011CB: load (dictionary.c:111)
==18981==    by 0x4008CD: main (speller.c:41)
```

So, my interpretation of this output is that, in the following block of code:

```
        if (current_node->children[index] == NULL)
        {
            current_node->children[index] = malloc(sizeof(node));

            // if we cannot allocate the memory, unload and return false
            if (current_node->children[index] == NULL)
            {
                unload();
                return false;
            }

        }
```

the `malloc` statement (which is indeed line dictionary.c:111) is executed twice such that the allocated memory is never freed. (Is this correct?) Now, that leads me to think that the real problem lies with my clear function, i.e. that it is written poorly and does not clear every node of my trie.

However, I've stared at the code for hours and I literally cannot see anything wrong with it. (I'm sure a lot is; I'm just not too good at this.)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

As a sidenote: I've had multiple people (not course staff) tell me that I should initialize all of my pointers in the children array to NULL, but the course staff outright told me this was optional, and I have already tested it both ways with the same results. I know it's probably a portability thing even if it technically "works" like that, but just know that that is *not* the solution I am looking for, as I know there is some other root cause (i.e. one that causes it to not work on any device at all whatsoever...)

Again, if you can help in any way with what is wrong with my logic here, I would greatly appreciate it. I have been trying to figure this out for hours to no avail.

Comment: Intentional. As I mentioned, I tested the program both with and without the pointer initializations (for root and all of the children arrays) with the same results.

Comment: Actually, we are being ranked on runtime, so technically as long as it compiles and "works" without leaking memory we are encouraged to cut anything unnecessary, so I cut it. I will concede that it's a bit of a "wrong" approach to developing in general, though.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly this question, before I started to consider it unfixable

Comment: Get it right before worrying about speed.  Remember the basic rules of optimization: (1) Don't do it! (2) (for experts only) Don't do it yet.

Comment: Have you printed the value of `index` before you use it?  Valgrind is telling you that it is out of control (value probably `-2`) when it tells you that the code is reading 16 bytes before a block.   Either use extensive printing or step through with a debugger.  You are also dicing with death not ensuring that your allocated data is properly initialized.  I pointed that out in my answer to one of your previous questions; Lundin has pointed it out in his answer.  If you knew more about C than we do, you wouldn't be asking the question.  Please, pay attention.

Comment: I don't think all of you understand. I don't enjoy writing terrible code. My grade very much depends on how fast the code runs, and everyone in the class has the same asymptotic runtime. So essentially, my grade depends on being a terrible coder and cutting out anything I can afford to cut out that might actually be essential

Comment: You have glaring out-of-bounds reads in the code, and your question is about leaks?

Comment: So, yes, I agree with your concerns. But I can't afford to listen to them, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Kaz I included those in the valgrind output. I assume those are in no small way related to the leaks. But yes, thank you for the very helpful comment

Comment: Your grade depends on the code working correctly and fast.  Leaks would be a non-issue if fast was all.  But your code is incorrect.  You need to fix it first.  Then work on speed.  You will lose unless you get the sequence right: correct first, fast second.

Comment: Oh, it already works correctly. I'm honestly not even sure what the leaks are affecting to be honest, which sounds bad, but it already has passed without fail every staff devised test for correctness.

Comment: Leaks often don't matter in a program which is a short-lived utility that quits soon after it is invoked. Even in a long-lived program, leaks may not matter if they are fixed,  one-time leaks. Leaks matter most in a long-running application that is repeatedly losing track of memory in a loop.

Comment: I'm not even allowed to turn this in if there are any leaks.

Comment: How can you say it works correctly when it's reading out of bounds? It's possible for out-of-bounds reading programs to be correct, but it requires additional justification.

Comment: I don't make the tests. They passed the spell checker about 50 classic novels or so continuously as input, and it spell checked them with 100% accuracy. Like I don't know what you are asking at this point.

Answer (score 4):

```
root = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

This gives a chunk of uninitialized memory.

```
if (current_node->children[index] == NULL)
```

Here you assume that the memory has been initialized, while it is actually garbage.

You need to initialize the contents of `root` before using them, or alternatively use calloc to set them all to zero.

Comment: As I said, I have tested the code both with and without initializing those pointers to NULL. I also have tested it both with and without calloc. It helps nothing but portability, which is actually discouraged for this assignment because it is not required and will increase runtimes noticeably. That is not the root of my memory error (at least on the machine where the code compiles, which is all that matters here), considering I get the exact same errors when I take those precautions.

Comment: @mattstone The contents of `malloc`:ed memory can be any garbage. It is not a portability issue, you always have to initialize them. If your program for some reason worked without you doing so, it was out of sheer (bad) luck.

Comment: I'm unsure of why, but we were outright told that this was not needed. To be fair, we submit the code online, where it is compiled and tested for correctness somewhere else, so maybe they have that worked out or something? I don't know why they did that. I agree it's not smart. But the result is consistent. And this could also relate to the fact that I allocate all memory and then free all of it without any complicated interactions possible once the program is already running.

Comment: @mattstone The people who told you so were incompetent. This is quite basic stuff. Formally it is specified by the standard C11 7.22.3.4 "The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate."

Comment: @mattstone In addition, you should sanity check the value of `int index = (tolower(*word) - 'a') % CHARVALUES;` to see that it doesn't get set to something out of bounds.

Comment: Okay, well I have indeed tested the code the other way with the same errors, so is there anything else besides the malloc thing that you see an issue with? I have already explained that I tested it both ways. I can transition into that if it is necessary, but the problem still will not be solved

Comment: Also, I'm fairly confident that that line of code does what it's supposed to do. I literally even have a check already coded there too that ensures index is no larger than 26. So I honestly don't think that's an issue

Comment: @mattstone Not easy to say without knowing the caller code. The Valgrid log is pretty useless without it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to

Comment: @mattstone You didn't post the code with `main` which Valgrids whines about.

Comment: I can post it, but I'm not allowed to edit that source file. Hold on.

Comment: @mattstone: Note that not only does index have to be no larger than 26; it also has to be no smaller than zero.  Valgrind is telling you that you have a negative value.  Note that one easy way to get a negative index is to have an upper-case letter in the input.  I've not idea whether that's actually the problem, but when things break, you add checks to rule out possibilities.  Then when you find the cause, you can decide what to do about eliminating now unnecessary checks.

Comment: Just from a fundamentally mathematical standpoint, the modulus of two numbers is always greater than or equal to zero. I see your logic, but I don't see why this would ever be the case

Comment: @mattstone Mathematicians tend to make horrible programmers, because they assume that C behaves 1) rationally and 2) like math. It does neither. C does all manner of irrational things to your expressions, like implicit type promotion or dysfunctional division of negative numbers (before the C99 standard). It has unspecified signedness of the char type, etc etc. It is a very flawed language, but the flaws are well-known.

Answer (score 0):

After switching both malloc() statements with calloc() (as suggested by others; this removes your otherwise numerous valgrind errors), adding a small sample dictionary, and the following minimalist main():

```
int main() {

    load("dict.txt");

    printf("Checked: %i\n", check("hello"));
    printf("Checked: %i\n", check("sdfsdf"));

    unload();

    return 0;
}
```

... your code runs much more cleanly and without any memory leaks:

```
==636== HEAP SUMMARY:
==636==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==636==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 42,688 bytes allocated
==636==
==636== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==636==
==636== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 8)
```

One obvious leak you will have though is if you return false from load() - you won't free the file-pointer.

Edit: Valgrind starts to throw up all sorts of errors (again) when you introduce uppercase words to the dictionary. So concentrate your debugging efforts there.